# How to migrate PicketBox custom login module to Elytron?

Tags: java, security, jboss, wildfly

I have an application that deploys on Wildfly and in the standalone there is this entry:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
    <security-domains>
        <security-domain name="customLoginModule" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="com.mypackage.MyLoginModule flag="required"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
...
```

There is also this class:

```
public class MyLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule {

    public static void authenticateUser(HttpServletRequest request, String principalName) {
        try {
            request.login(principalName, "PasswordKey");
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("...");
        }
    }

    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {

        super.iniitalize(subject, callbackHandler, sharedState, options);
    }

    private static Group[] createUserGroup() {

        SimpleGroup group = new SimpleGroup("Roles");

        group.addMember(new SimplePrincipal("MyUser"));

        return new Group[]{group};
    }

    @Override
    protected String getUsersPassword() {
        return "PasswordKey";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validatePassword(String input, String expected) {
        return input.equals(expected);
    }

    @Override
    protected Group[] getRoleSets() {
        return createUserGroup();
    }
}
```

Inside our login servlet, the static method authenticateUser() is called.

I do not understand exactly what is the point of this class and how security is working. The need is to remove the PicketBox dependency that provides UsernamePasswordLoginModule because it uses this deprecated Group class. How can I modify the above logic and security-domain in the standalone.xml to work with Elyton security? I read this [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Migrate%20Legacy%20Security%20to%20Elytron%20Security.html#119144556_MigrateLegacySecuritytoElytronSecurity-PicketBoxBasedConfiguration) but I am not able to understand how it could be applied in my case. Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm no expert, but maybe this will help http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-security/how-to-create-a-custom-elytron-realm/

Comment: were you able to find a solution? am stuck on this as well, migrating from wildfly 10 to wildfly 27

Answer (score 0):

That login module appears to hardcode the password to PasswordKey.

But if you're looking to translate it to Elytron, custom realms should extend `org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityRealm` in the same sort of way that yours extends `UserNamePasswordLoginModule`.  See `MasterTheBoss`, as was suggested above.